# $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] wrong link, double link

Tags: php, self

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` gives the wrong link and because of that some scripts don't work correctly

For example, I put the following code in the file `test.php`:

```
<?
echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF];
echo "<br>" ;
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>
```

In root folder, like `www.site.ru/test.php`, I see:

```
/test.php/test.php
/test.php/test.php
```

Must be just /test.php... why does that happen?

Php version:

```
php.i686 0:5.3.16-9
php-cli.i686 0:5.3.16-9 
php-common.i686 0:5.3.16-9
php-devel.i686 0:5.3.16-9
php-fpm.i686 0:5.3.16-9
php-pdo.i686 0:5.3.16-9
php-sqlite.i686 0:5.3.16-9
php-xml.i686 0:5.3.16-9
php-mysql.i686 0:5.3.16-9
php-mcrypt.i686 0:5.3.16-9
php-mbstring.i686 0:5.3.16-9
php-intl.i686 0:5.3.16-9
php-gd.i686 0:5.3.16-9
```

Comment: it works okay for me, could you provide any other information?

Comment: use only this one and see if it's still shown duplicated: var_dump($_SESSION['PHP_SELF']);

Comment: Do you have any rewrite rules in your web server configuration?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Have you found a solution to this?  I am using Abyss webserver and have no URL rewrite rules or anything like that ... just a basic setup.

Answer (score 1):

**cgi.fix-pathinfo**

I was have the same problem , after lot of search found the fix for my problem also sure for you too

I use nginx/1.10.2 with PHP 5.6.29 with PHP-FPM

`var_dump($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); = 'string(32)"/test/index3.php/test/index3.php"'`

to fix , edit php.ini cgi.fix_pathinfo make sure its equal 0

cgi.fix_pathinfo provides *real* PATH_INFO/PATH_TRANSLATED support for CGI.  PHP's
previous behaviour was to set PATH_TRANSLATED to SCRIPT_FILENAME, and to not grok
what PATH_INFO is.  For more information on PATH_INFO, see the cgi specs.  Setting
this to 1 will cause PHP CGI to fix its paths to conform to the spec.  A setting
of zero causes PHP to behave as before.  Default is 1.  You should fix your scripts
to use SCRIPT_FILENAME rather than PATH_TRANSLATED.
http://php.net/cgi.fix-pathinfo

`cgi.fix_pathinfo=0`

after fix the problem

should restart nginx and php-fpm

`var_dump($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); = 'string(16) "/test/index3.php"'`